# Парсинг bashorg.org для бота

Tags: python, парсер, telebot, bs4

Написал простого бота в телеге, который по запросу отправляет цитаты с баша. Но бота хватает на 20 цитат.(именно столько их на 1 странице). Не могу сообразить как мне его заставить все страницы парсить? Строго не судите, я новичок.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

def quote(url):
    r = requests.get('http://bashorg.org/page/1')
    html = b(r.text,'html.parser')
    citt = html.find_all('div', class_='quote')
    return [c.text for c in citt]

URL='http://bashorg.org/page/1'
quotes = quote(URL)

bot = telebot.TeleBot('''''''''''''''''')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['начать'])
def hello(message):
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, введи любую цифру до 9.')
     
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def cit(message):
    if message.text.lower() in ('123456789'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (quotes[1]))
        del quotes[0]
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи любую цифру ДО 9')
        
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: `http://bashorg.org/page/2`, `http://bashorg.org/page/3`, ...

Comment: Не совсем представляю как это реализовать. Бот должен отвечать до тех пор пока не закончатся все страницы, а их там 2021. Это ~ 40000 цитат.   Нужно что бы бот автоматом переходил на другую страницу, когда цитаты закончатся на первой

Comment: В чем проблема рандомить страницу?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: `r = requests.get(f'http://bashorg.org/page/{random.randint(1, max_page)}')`

Comment: Да, это классно работает, но не до конца. В таком случае бот берет рандомную страницу и забирает от туда 20 цитат, после чего останавливается. Я дописал условие и всё заработало как надо.    `if len(quotes) == 0:
            quotes = quote(URL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну видимо как-то так:

```py
def quote(url):
    global page
    r = requests.get(f'{url}{page}')
    page += 1
    ...

URL='http://bashorg.org/page/'
page = 1
quotes = quote(URL)
...
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (quotes[0])) # индекс 0, а не 1
        del quotes[0]
        if len(quotes) == 0:
            quotes = quote(URL)
...
```

То есть когда цитаты заканчиваются подчитываем очередную порцию с сайта.

Comment: Это похоже на решение проблемы, но глобальная переменная не работает. ..page подчеркнуто красным в строке global page.    >>name 'page' is parameter and global

Comment: @ДмитрийСериков Забыл убрать из параметров функции когда код переделывал. Поправил

Comment: Благодарю, теперь всё работает как надо.